# Bazel: srcs are not executed on genrule

Tags: bazel

In Bazel, I defined this macro and rule.

```
def custom_macros(name, **kwargs):
  rust_binary(
    name = name,
    **kwargs
  )

  native.genrule(
    name = "gen_" + name,
    srcs = [":" + name],
    outs = ["out_gen_" + name],
    cmd = "cp $(SRCS) $(OUTS)"
  )
```

```
custom_macros(
  name = "sample",
  srcs = ["sample.rs"],
)
```

I executed this command `bazel build //:gen_sample`. I'm expected to put out `out_gen_sample`, because official document says that `The build system ensures these prerequisites are built before running the genrule command.` in the section of `srcs` of `genrules`. But it failed. It seems that `:sample` was not executed. I'm confusing this behavior.

Comment: Yes, and it should work. If you only expect on in/out, it might make sense to say `$<`/`$@` instead of `$(SRCS)`/`$(OUTS)`. But this should work and with generic replacement it did for me, check `rust_binary` and single output file should be in `DefaultInfo` just the same. What error message are you getting?

Comment: Thank you for answering! I got this error. `ERROR: BUILD:12:1: Executing genrule //:out_gen_sample failed (Exit 1) bash failed: error executing command /bin/bash -c 'source external/bazel_tools/tools/genrule/genrule-setup.sh;` It seems that `cp` command is executed but failed to catch `$(SRCS)`, and `$</$@` didn't work fine.

Comment: It worked fine in another environment. It seems that this is not a problem of `genrule`. Thanks!